# Remove everything inside two BBcode-like tags

Tags: php

I have the following string stored in a variable (which is taken from a database)

```
$string = 'some simple text i need [link href="http://www.somelink.com/..."]some link i dont need here[/link] some simple text i need too.';
```

I'm trying to remove the following part from the string:

```
[link href="http://www.somelink.com/..."]some link i dont need here[/link]
```

This is the final output I wish to have:

```
some simple text i need some simple text i need too.
```

How can I accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: `preg_match('#(\[link.*?\].*?\[/link\])#', $string, $matches); echo $matces[1]`

Comment: @AmalMurali, Typo there. `$matches[1]` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex `~\[link(.*?)\[\/link]~`

```
<?php
$string = 'some simple text i need [link href="http://www.somelink.com/..."]some link i dont need here[/link] some simple text i need too.';
echo $str = preg_replace("~\[link(.*?)\[\/link]~","", $string);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
some simple text i need some simple text i need too.
```

[image]

Comment: I believe what the OP wants is a new string with the part that matches deleted, which is what the `preg_replace()` statement does.